# Equation $a+k \pmod{b+k} = 0$ and the smallest $k$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We let's equation:

$a+k \pmod{b+k} = 0$

For example:

$a = 153$;
$b = 52$;

We are looking for the smallest $k$ giving solution

$153+k \pmod {52+k} = 0$

The correct result is $k=49$ becouse:

$153+49 \pmod {52+49} = 202 \pmod {101} = 0$

What is the quickest way to calculate $k$?
I need a very quick way.

Comment: I have never seen that notation before.  Does it mean $a+k\equiv 0 \pmod {(b+k)}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry - my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a-b (mod b+k)  is also 0;

k is the (minimal divisor of a-b greater then b) - b

Comment: Any faster way exist?

Comment: probably no - is the equivalent of the factorisation problem